# Simple class calling issue with CSS

Tags: html, css

Not a web developer so i hope you will spare me if this question does not make sense.I tried many ways but due to lack of knowledge of CSS its not working for me.

i have a page with following structure

```
<div id="content">
   <div class="archive">
      <div class="left-archive">
         <h3><a>Main Left tile</a></h3>
        <ul>
         <li><a link>Link title</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="right-archive">
          <h3><a>Main Right tile</a></h3>
        <ul>
         <li><a link> Link title</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Now my intention was that when the page first display all link should be underlined and when i hover over them `text-decoration` should be `none`.
i write this css code

```
.archive  ul li a:hover{
  text-decoration:none;
  outline:medium none;
}
.archive   ul li  a:visited {
  color:#4280B4;
  text-decoration:underline;
}

 .archive h3 a:visited{
  color:#CE4F00;
  text-decoration:underline;
}


.archive   h3 a:hover{
  color:#3C78A7;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

but this is not working and its picking the following CSS entry from same CSS file

```
a:link, a:visited {
    color: #3c78a7;
    text-decoration:none
    }

a:hover, a:active {
    color: #3c78a7;
    text-decoration:underline;
    }
```

Honestly what i did was simple hit and trial nothing being logical.Can any one guide me to right path how i can achieve correct behavioral.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It might depened on what comes first in your CSS file. Try to replace them by each other.

Comment: You have too many spaces in your selectors. Is it like that in the code or is it a formatting issue on SO?

Comment: @MichaelSazonov:the defintion i mention in last coming first in the css and what i have defined is at the end of file

Comment: @Filip: Must be my cause just playing around with css :)

Comment: @user577691 And what if you remove them? Does that solve it?

Comment: They're not valid <a> anchors for a start.

Comment: @Filip: What's wrong with having too many spaces?

Comment: @Filip:no when i removed them it just made everything underlined but not doing anything when i am hovering over the links

Comment: @BoltClock I was looking at the selector `.archive   ul` for example and I just assumed that having that many spaces in the selector could make some browsers act weird. But if not I'm more than happy to learn.

Comment: @Filip: Nah, whitespace isn't an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe because you have not written the css attributes for a general anchor tag link. Something like

```
.archive ul li a 
 {
   text-decoration:underline;
 }

 .archive ul li a:hover
 {
   text-decoration:none;
 }
```

Then when you hover, you will get the intended effect.

Comment: Thanks that solved most of the issues and rest i figured out myself

Answer (score 1):

**You have to specify the styles in a particular order when you define them**:

```
link

visited

active

hover
```

**Edit**: response to your comment. The physical order that you write the CSS matters for anchors (`a` tags). In the CSS that is being used (your third code snippet), the CSS code for the `visited` links appears before the code for the `active` links.

In your own code in the second snippet, you have the CSS for `ul li` with `hover` before `visited`. You should simply reverse the order of those two CSS rules.

I'm not sure why your CSS for `h3` doesn't work, except perhaps it wants a CSS rule for `link`.

Comment: Can you define a bit.Being new to CSS i am not sure what exact this means :)

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you want.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   .archive  ul li a:hover{
   text-decoration:none;
   outline:medium none;
  }
 .archive   ul li  a:visited {
 color:#4280B4;
 text-decoration:underline;
}

 .archive h3 a:visited{
 color:#CE4F00;
 text-decoration:underline;
}


.archive   h3 a:hover{
color:#3C78A7;
text-decoration:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<div class="archive">
  <div class="left-archive">
     <h3><a>Main Left tile</a></h3>
    <ul>
     <li><a class="link" href="#">Link title</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="right-archive">
      <h3><a>Main Right tile</a></h3>
    <ul>
     <li><a class="link" href="#"> Link title</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>  
</body>
```

Your value for the hrefs may vary.
The only things changed are the anchor tag parts.

Answer (score 0):

add this at the end of your css

```
li a
{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in some browsers the `<a>` (anchor) tag will not render as a hoverable link unless you specifiy an actual href='#'

This is the case in Chrome anyway. If I specify hrefs for the 4 `<a>`'s in your example html it works.

```
<div id="content">
   <div class="archive">
      <div class="left-archive">
         <h3><a href="#">Main Left tile</a></h3>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Link title</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="right-archive">
          <h3><a href="#">Main Right tile</a></h3>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#"> Link title</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: sorry for not providing full information in this case.I have `href` in my `<a>` tag and even links are coming fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have anchors and no links. You also added underlines to all link, which is the opposite of what you said you wanted. I added an 'a' so that your style would apply to them as well. Also, there is no 'link' attribute for the anchor tag.

Here is a live example as well: http://jsfiddle.net/khalifah/jymK3/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            a, a:link, a:visited {
                color: #3c78a7;
                text-decoration: underline
            }

            a:hover, a:active {
                color: #3c78a7;
                text-decoration: underline
            }

            .archive ul li a:hover{
                text-decoration: none;
                outline: medium none
            }
            .archive ul li a:visited {
                color: #4280B4;
                text-decoration: underline
            }

            .archive h3 a:visited{
                color: #CE4F00;
                text-decoration: underline
            }

            .archive h3 a:hover{
                color: #3C78A7;
                text-decoration: none
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <div class="archive">
                <div class="left-archive">
                    <h3><a>Main Left tile</a></h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a>Link title</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="right-archive">
                    <h3><a>Main Right tile</a></h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a> Link title</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </body>
<html>
```